# Swift/Xcode: Why does the tab bar disapear if I navigate away from the page?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tabs

So I have a list of exercises.  Each exercise is a button that segues to a screen that shows a video of the exercise.  I then have a back button on the video page that segues back to the initial list of exercise page.  However, when I segue back, the tab bar at the bottom is no longer there.  Any idea why it's disapearing? Thanks so much!
[image: Hi! So I have a list of exercises. Each exercise is a button that segues to a screen that shows a video of the exercise. I then have a back button on the video page that segues back to the initial list of exercise page. However, when I segue back, the tab bar at the bottom is no longer there. Any idea why it's disapearing? Thanks so much!]

Comment: are you hidding tabbar in any controller ?

Comment: Do you have "hide bottom bar on push" selected in your Attributes Inspector? Are you using a library or any code for your video players that might be hiding the tab bar?

Comment: @shim nope it is not selected

Comment: @jawadAli how would I check if I am? I don't think I am but not sure

Comment: @shim I am just using webkit.  I am ok with the tab bar not being visible on the video pages, I just need the tab bar to reappear when they navigate back to the list page

Comment: Have you tried something like `self.tabBarController.tabBar.isHidden = false`?

Comment: You are showing toolbar on video playing view controller so my guess is you are hiding toolbar in swift class. Check if tabBarController.tabBar.isHidden = true in that class and if so then add tabBarController.tabBar.isHidden = false in your initial list exercise page viewwillappear method.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about last answer it was for some other question on stackoverflow just misplaced it. Please take a look in your on video page controller if you have this selected. Also check if you have these lines in your code

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

[image: Check out the one pointed out]

Answer (score 0):

Change your segue to perform segue to `TAB BAR CONTROLLER`

Create a UITabBarController file. Inside it , create a struct and a simple if condition

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    struct defaultIndexSelection {

    static var selectedIndex = "0"

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        if defaultIndexSelection.selectedIndex == "0"
        {
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
        }
        else if defaultIndexSelection.selectedIndex == "1"
        {
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
        }
        else if defaultIndexSelection.selectedIndex == "2"
        {
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
        }
        else if defaultIndexSelection.selectedIndex == "3"
        {
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 3
        }
    }
```

Set this `TabBarController` as the class of your TabBarController.

Now on your back buttons action , add this line.

```
TabBarController.defaultIndexSelection.selectedIndex = 0
// if you want to have the tab at index 0 selected and 
shown on back button press or 1 if you want first tab selected
```

Thats it, whenever you press back from whatever viewController, it will segue back to tabbarcontroller and then select the index depending on which viewcontroller you came from.

```
TabBarController.defaultIndexSelection.selectedIndex = 0 being your 1st tab
TabBarController.defaultIndexSelection.selectedIndex = 1 being your 2nd tab
TabBarController.defaultIndexSelection.selectedIndex = 2 being your 3rd tab
TabBarController.defaultIndexSelection.selectedIndex = 3 being your 4th tab
```